# Support for tensor type hints (variadic generics) in Numpy (PEP 646)

Tags: numpy, pep, python-3.11

**Context**: As of [Python 3.11](https://docs.python.org/3.11/whatsnew/3.11.html), variadic generics are supported as detailed in [PEP 646](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/). The idea behind variadic generics is to facilitate the annotation of tensors (or multiple dimensional arrays), like this example (from [PEP 646](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/)):

```py
def to_gray(videos: Array[Time, Batch, Height, Width, Channels]): ...
```

Tensor shape annotations really seem like a life saver, and I can't wait to use.
I am specifically interested in how this will pan out for Numpy. I did find some older  [discussion on github](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/16547) how they plan to annotate shape and dtypes of tensors. However, I didn't manage to get a birds eye view what is the current roadmap for implementing tensor type annotations.

**Question**: When, if ever, will Numpy plan to support the shape type annotations as given in the above example?

Comment: This question would be more appropriate on the [NumPy mailing list](https://numpy.org/community/) than here on stackoverflow.

Comment: The OP probably posted this if one wants to follow or revive: https://mail.python.org/archives/list/numpy-discussion@python.org/message/M64GNODUUYXJY57EKATWLADK35PRAV4Q/.